# Memory leak(?) Python 3.2

Tags: python, memory

Hi I am new to python and I have read enough posts for the specific subject but none has a specific answer. (using py 64-bit 3.2 edition)

I have a big input which I read it inside a loop and as I read the file I create groups which I append to a List . I process the List and then store it inside a file. I unreffer the List (List = None) and I delete it. I even call gc collector manually. Problem is that the memory is still been used. Swap space and Ram go wild.

```
for line in file: # read line by line
        temp_buffer = line.split() # split elements
        for word in temp_buffer: #enumerate (?)
             if not l1: # list is empty
                 l1.append(str(word)) #store '-' to list 
             else:      # list is not empty
                 tempp = l1.pop(0)
                 l1.insert(0,"-0")
                 l1.sort(key=int)
                 l2 = term_compress(l1)

                 l1 = None # delete referrences
                 del l1    # delete struct

                 print(" ".join(str(i) for i in l2) , file=testfile) # print for every term in file
                 l2 = None # delete referrences
                 del l2    # delete struct

                 gc.collect() # run garbagge collector (free RAM)
                 l1 = [] 
                 l2 = []
                 l1.append(str(word))
```

What am I doing wrong ?

edit

example input:

```
-a 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

-n 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 ...
```

output

```
-a 1# 10#

-n 7# 15#
```

Comment: What is `term_compress()`?

Comment: Also, the problem sounds like something for which it should be easy to come up with an SSCCE (http://www.sscce.org/). Perhaps you could come up with one and add it to your question?

Comment: term_compress is a function which process the list and returns a list which is always smaller that the input of the function. For small input script runs smooth, for large input I get MemoryError. term_compress finds the gaps between each item and trying to compress the items

Comment: check if the memory leak can be avoided adding `import gc`, `gc.collect()` (`gc` is the garbage collector module) after the `term_compress()` call, the problem may be there

Comment: done that, nothing it even reduces speed of script

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: ubuntu 12.04  64 bit , I had bugs(encoding) using windows

Comment: Assigning to `None` before deleting shouldn't make a difference. Speaking more generally: You shouldn't be thinking in terms of allocating and deallocating memory yourself. That's the point of automatic garbage collection. How big is your input?

Comment: small inputs are like 3~10mb bit is 20GB

Comment: 20GB is pretty big. Keep in mind that every element of a list is actually a reference to some object. So that's at least 8 bytes (for 64-bit addresses) per element, without even counting the space for the *data* which belongs to that element. Python has plenty of other overhead as well. Ultimately, what you think of as 20GB worth of data could easily take many times that amount of memory when held in Python data structures.

Comment: Also note that the internal representation of strings became somewhat more efficient with Python 3.3 (see [PEP 393](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/)).

Comment: I will try 3.3 or 3.4 and hope I won't get crash again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely not a memory/reference leak in the traditional sense of a programming error.  What you're likely seeing is the underlying C runtime aggressively holding on to heap memory that Python allocated on your behalf during the loop. It's anticipating that you might need to use that memory again. Holding onto it is cheaper than giving it back to the OS kernel only to ask for it again and again.

So, in short, even though your objects have been garbage collected in the [Python runtime](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/memory.html), the [underlying C runtime](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Freeing-after-Malloc) hangs onto the heap memory in case your program needs it again.

From the glibc documentation:

> Occasionally, free can actually return memory to the operating system and make the process smaller. Usually, all it can do is allow a later call to malloc to reuse the space. In the meantime, the space remains in your program as part of a free-list used internally by malloc.

In that sense, your memory utilization reported by the OS after the loop is basically your "peak memory utilization".  If you think it's too high, then you have to consider redesigning your program to limit its peak memory usage.  This is typically accomplished using some kind of streaming or buffering design where you're operating on smaller chunks of the data at a time.

Disclaimer, the above is a layman's version and is obviously implementation specific to various flavors of Python, C, and the OS.